# How can I pass an input parameter as a method call on an object

Tags: javascript, methods, call

```
function callContract(ABI, Address, functionName) {
    var Contract = eth.contract(ABI).at(Address);
    var getData = Contract.functionName.getData(5);
```

Is there any way to pass the functionName and use that functionName to call on the Contract object?

Comment: Do you mean how do you access an object property whose name is stored in `functionName`?

Comment: Yeah thats what I mean, the property being functionName

Comment: @kquinn I've added another duplicate [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/1048572) which is exctly what you want.